# Shell commands that do not launch a new process

Tags: shell, system

What are some system commands that do not launch a separate process?
I think `cd` is one. Are there any others?
What about the commands `more` and `less`?

Comment: These are called "built-ins". See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html for the list of special built-ins (commands that *must* be built-in for a POSIX-compliant shell, typically because their operation impacts that shell's state).

Comment: That said, I don't believe this question is on-topic here -- StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions *exclusively* related to software development, whereas understanding what builtins are is pertinent to general users, not software developers alone. Consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) lists all built-in commands, which I believe will be run in the same process as the shell. Other shells should list them in their own manuals, and any posix compatible shell (including bash) must build in the `type` command, which can be used to find out whether another command is built-in. I don’t see `more` or `less` in the built-in list for bash so they must run in separate processes.